# Write a spring bean with a constructor that contains a list of values from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

Could you help me what the proper way of writing spring bean with parameter of list **values** which I get from **.properties file.**

```
  <bean id="property" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:dateFormat.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="directoryMarshallerFolder1" class="threadService.DirectoryMarshalerFolder1">

    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            ...
            <value = "${folder1.path}"/> ?????
            <value = "${folder2.path}"/> 
            ...
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already found the result.

```
 <constructor-arg> <list> <value>${folder1.path}</value> <value>${folder2.path}</value> </list> </constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell spring to load your property file :

```
<bean name="propertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Please note that your file application.properties must be in the classpath of your project (`src/main/resources` is a good pick if you use the maven way)

Then you can use the constructor-arg tag to populate your bean :

```
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="${property.key1}"/>
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="${property.key2}"  />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. But my question connected to annother idea.

Comment: I've already have found the result.
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>${folder1.path}</value>
                <value>${folder2.path}</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>

Comment: So please post it as an answer to your own question ! :)